# Jenkins Pipeline - How to combine values of 2 different parameters into one field?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 different fields build_label and app_name need to combine both values and display for buildName={ } parameter how do i add this in Jenkins pipeline script?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
buildNumber = "$build_label $app_name"
```